# Best practice in powershell Try/Catch/Finally scripting?

Tags: powershell

I wonder if this is possible to remove all variables used in the current script session?

```
Try {
    Write-Host "Scripting start...."
}
Catch {
    Write-Warning -Message "[PROCESS] Something wrong happened"
    Write-Warning -Message $Error[0].Exception.Message
}
Finally {
    Remove-Variable *
    [System.GC]::Collect() 
}
```

If not, what can I do in the `Finally` block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a best practice to name your custom variable with some entropy so that they are easily found and removed. Removing '*' removes everything regardless of when/how it was created, including all PS default variables.

Don't do this.

At each session run, collect that defaults and automatic ones in a variable, before you end your session compare that variable collection to what you created and only remove what you created.

So, in my case, I'd use, say ...

```
$panVariableName
```

... then

```
Remove-Variable -Name 'pan*' -Force
```

Or if you do not want to do it this way. At session start, do this...

```
$AutomaticVariables = Get-Variable
```

... then you can compare any variables you create regardless of what you name them to get your removal collection. Here is a function I keep in my module profile for such use cases for cleanup relative to this approach.

So, in my module profile, this is at the top...

```
$AutomaticVariables = Get-Variable
```

Then when I am ready this function is called.

```
Function Clear-ResourceEnvironment
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('cre')]
    
    Param
    (
        [switch]$AdminCredStore
    )
    
 
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [GC]::Collect()
    [GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    
    Get-PSSession | 
    Remove-PSSession -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
    If ($AdminCredStore)
    {Remove-Item -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\AdminCredSet.xml" -Force}
    Else 
    {
        Write-Warning -Message "`n`t`tYou decided not to delete the custom Admin credential store. 
        This store is only valid for this host and user $env:USERNAME"
    } 
    
    Write-Warning -Message "`n`t`tRemoving the displayed session specific variable ojects"
    
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Variable) -DifferenceObject $AutomaticVariables -Property Name -PassThru | 
    Where -Property Name -ne 'AutomaticVariables' | 
    Remove-Variable -Verbose -Force -Scope 'global' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Variable -Name AdminCredStore -Verbose -Force
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can use:

```bsh
Clear-Variable * -Scope Global
```

OR

```bsh
Remove-Variable * -Scope Global
```

Alternatively, would scoping the process resolve your issue? You can create a `scriptblock` and call it with the "call operator" (`&`). This would run the process in a scoped env separate from the global one. It would look something like this:

```bsh
$scriptBlock = { 
    Try {
        Write-Host "Scripting start...."
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Warning -Message "[PROCESS] Something wrong happened"
        Write-Warning -Message $Error[0].Exception.Message
    }
    Finally {
        [System.GC]::Collect() 
    }
}

&$scriptBlock
```

You'd have no need to Remove-Variable, because after the execution, anything that occurred within the scope in terms of variables is already gone.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, thankyou for the quick reply.
So if I run the script locally, is that $ScriptBlock envelop will be applicable?

Comment: Yea, should be viable. Not entirely sure what variables you're clearing, but should work. I'm actually not entirely sure if it creates a new scope for the $Error variables. You may have to test that, if that's one of the variables you're concerned with clearing.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, what I'd like to clear is all variables that have been created within the scope of the current script execution.

Comment: Awesome, so if it's in that try/catch, then you can have them drop from the scoped call operator (&). Otherwise the other options should work if called at the end.